# Google Webmaster starred queries limit: 100 vs 80?

Tags: google-search-console

While using Google Webmaster I was starring some queries and bumped into "Sorry, we allow a maximum of 100 starred queries."

But at the filters it's showing "Starred queries only ‎(80)‎".

What's going on here?

[image: Google Webmaster Screenshot]

Comment: It sounds to me like the limit is actually 80 and the error message has an incorrect number.